# Asp.Net Role-based authentication using Security groups in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, role

I am attempting to do something simple (I thought) - securing my application using roles-based security using Active Directory groups in our Domain.

Specifically, I need to show/hide items on a page depending upon whether the currently logged in user is part of `domain\groupA` in Active Directory. For some reason, it is difficult finding information on using Active Directory for this. Everything I seem to find goes into details of using forms-based authentication using roles, or it uses a DB to store the information.

All I want to do is use our already outlined security structure in our Active Directory. Can someone please explain what I need?

Do I need:

1. `<roleManager enabled="true"/>` in `web.config`
2. `<allow roles ="domain\groupA"/>` in `web.config`
3. IIS set to windows authentication
4. `if (User.IsInRole(@"domain\groupA")){ //do stuff }` in my page?

What else am I missing? Anything? 'cause its not working. heh.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably just need to add a RoleProvider to your web.config to tell the app how to do searches against AD.

Sample code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx).

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider" 
  enabled="true"
  cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="WindowsProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```